# Error when converting LaTeX-generated PDF to PNG using ImageMagick's convert command in Python

Tags: python, imagemagick

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to convert a LaTeX-generated PDF to a PNG image in Python using ImageMagick's `convert` command. The error message I'm facing is as follows:

Invalid Parameter - C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpdxeaziux\tikz_figure.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/twill/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/Programming/Python/clipboard.py", line 50, in 
image = Image.open(image_file)
File "C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2878, in open
fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpdxeaziux\tikz_figure.png'

**Problem Description:**
I have a Python project where I'm generating an image from a TikZ code snippet using LaTeX and aiming to display it in a tkinter window. The issue arises when I attempt to convert the PDF generated by LaTeX into a PNG image using the `convert` command from ImageMagick.

Here is the example I am working on:

```
from PIL import Image
import tempfile
import subprocess
import os

# Your TikZ code
latex_expr = r'''
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords,%
fill opacity=.5]
\tdplotsetpolarplotrange{0}{360}{0}{360}
\tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
{1+(1/5)*sin(6*\tdplottheta)*sin(5*\tdplotphi)}{black}{\tdplotphi}%
{\path[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
-- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{};}%
{\path[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
-- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{};}%
{\path[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
-- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{};}%
\end{tikzpicture}
'''

temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
latex_file = os.path.join(temp_dir, "tikz_figure.tex")
pdf_file = os.path.join(temp_dir, "tikz_figure.pdf")
image_file = os.path.join(temp_dir, "tikz_figure.png")

latex_doc = r'''
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
''' + latex_expr + r'''
\end{document}
'''

# Save TikZ code to a temporary LaTeX document
with open(latex_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(latex_doc)

# Compile the LaTeX document to generate a PDF
subprocess.call(['pdflatex', '-output-directory=' + temp_dir, latex_file])

# Convert the PDF to an image (PNG)
subprocess.call(['convert', pdf_file, image_file])

# Open and display the generated image
image = Image.open(image_file)
```

Comment: Please ensure your question is **minimal**. Is it *really* related to **PDF** and **ImageMagick** and **latex** and **Tk**? Or can you remove 2-3 aspects?

Comment: Pardon me @MarkSetchell, I'm doing my best to adhere to the principles and guidelines of stack overflow.  I will look into it and see if it warrants the removal of some tags. Thank you for your input.

Comment: It's not the tags that concern me, it is the code. Your chances of getting a good answer decrease every time you add a new technology/dimension. So whilst I am familiar with ImageMagick, once you add **Tk** and **Latex**, I'm going to leave it to someone else. And a **Tk** person is likely to see **Latex** and **ImageMagick** and not try to reply. The simpler, and more concise your question, the better your odds are of a good solution. Just saying.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I see. This will be difficult to do as what I'm trying to do depends on all of these technologies, but I'll do some diagnostics after I'm done volunteering today and try to narrow down the code. Thank you for your reply and I'll try to be better in the future.